# How to concatenate columns and find duplicates within?

Tags: vba, excel

- I have a Log sheet that is filled every time someone changes cells within other sheets. The Log has 6 columns reflecting "user name", "sheet name", "cell changed:address", "old value", "new value", "date and time" (run as macro indeed).
- To make this Log sheet easy-to-use for a supervisor, the idea was to fill red those lines which would have duplicates in "sheet name" and "cell changed:address" at the same time, but have different "user name" (this would mean the other user made changes to the content he or she did not create), and fill yellow those lines, that would have duplicates also in user column meaning the same user changed self-created content ("user name", "sheet name", "cell changed:address").
- As there will be many entries in Log and there will be new ones over time, it is not wise to use Conditional Formatting. Please, do not suggest this, it is not suitable (big and slow file).
- For VBA I thought I could use condition that If say C column is not empty and at the same time there is a duplicate within C&B Then If there is a duplicate within C&B&A = red (true) OR yellow (false).
- I tried to go step by step. I managed to find  duplicates in one column and fill them yellow. I learned from [here](http://analysistabs.com/vba/find-duplicate-values-column/):

  ```
  Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn()
  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
  Dim iCntr As Long
  lastRow = Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Row

  For iCntr = 2 To lastRow
  If Cells(iCntr, 3) <> "" Then
  matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 3), Range("C:C" & lastRow), 0)
  If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
     Cells(iCntr, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
     Cells(iCntr, 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
     Cells(iCntr, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow
     Cells(iCntr, 4).Interior.Color = vbYellow
     Cells(iCntr, 5).Interior.Color = vbYellow 
     End If
  End If
  Next
  End Sub
  ```
- I thought I could somehow "connect" rows of columns and find duplicates within the range as in the example above, that would be wrapped to a condition. However, I decided to use Union which I understand now was a nonsense? I first tried to connect C&B (while evading End(xlUp) attitude):

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim rng1 As Range
  Dim rng2 As Range
  Dim col2 As Range
  Dim col3 As Range
  Dim col3and2 As Range

  Set rng1 = Range("C:C").Find("*", [c1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
  Set rng2 = Range("B:B").Find("*", [b1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)

  If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    Set col3 = Range([c2], Cells(rng1.Row, 3))
    Set col2 = Range([b2], Cells(rng2.Row, 2))
  End If

  Set col3and2 = Application.Union(col3, col2)

  End Sub
  ```
- col3and2.Select worked on this, but as I tried to use it as a range to find duplicates within, I got stuck:

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
  Dim iCntr As Long
  Dim rng1 As Range
  Dim rng2 As Range
  Dim col2 As Long
  Dim col3 As Long
  Dim col3and2 As String

  Set rng1 = Range("C:C").Find("*", [c1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
  Set rng2 = Range("B:B").Find("*", [b1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)

  If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    col3 = Range([c2], Cells(rng1.Row, 3))
    col2 = Range([b2], Cells(rng2.Row, 2))
  End If

   col3and2 = Application.Union(col3, col2)
   lastRow = Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

  For iCntr = 2 To lastRow
    matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(col3&col2, col3and2, 0)
  If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
         Cells(iCntr, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
  End If
  Next iCntr
  End Sub
  ```
- I attach the messed up code, but I realise the attitude with Union was wrong as I did not understand the function properly. Is there a way out? Shall I just "hard concatenate" the cells to other column and look for duplicates there?  It feels as not VBA-fast-processing solution.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating combination of values you want to check in additional column is probably the fastest way to go. Anyway, I don't think there is much gain in applying vba automation instead of conditional formatting in this scenario. Also, if this is really large, shared file, Excel may not be the best solution to begin with.

At the moment I can think of one other way of searching for duplicates based on multiple columns using COUNTIFS function, but this is considerably slower. Below is an example based on two columns:

```
For iCntr = 1 To lastRow
  If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
    matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A1:A" & lastRow), Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("B1:B" & lastRow), Cells(iCntr, 2))
    If matchFoundIndex > 1 Then
      Cells(iCntr, 3) = "I've found one!"
    End If
  End If
Next
```

This differs slightly from the previous version, as it identify all duplicates, whereas Match version will not highlight first "original" value.

Comment: Dear Andrew, Thank you. The conditional formatting is not looking for the last value in Row or Column, but wants me to define formula in all range cells (like whole column), right? This means that every time somebody makes a change, the Log sheet wants to recalculate itself. For the kind of formatting I needed (I tried 150 000 Rows) it took about a minute and the file was 1.5 Mb. The thing is there may never be as many entries within the file, but I want to make sure it works without my help in future. VBA seems smarter to me.

Comment: Now I understand the code you proposed, I tried it and it works, thanks. However, if you say Concatenating the columns for the purpose of using Match function would be faster, what would you suggest to do exactly? I am not sure how to connect the result of Concatenating with the Match function.

Comment: I was thinking about physically concatenating values in additional "technical" column. On the other hand - you can format data you already have and then, going forward, loop through the records and make simple comparison. If you find even one record with the same values in three columns - you color new record red and exit the loop. If you find existing record with two values match - you color new one yellow and continue looping, because there may be still "red match" to be found. Basically you are comparing `Cells(iCntr, 3), Cells(iCntr, 2), Cells(iCntr, 1)` against values of the new record.

Comment: What I mean above is that you don't need to perform full "duplicates check" each time new record is entered. You are interested only in comparing this particular new record to existing data. Checking `If Cells(iCntr, 3) = Cells(newRow,3)` and the same for three columns.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I did this and for a while it worked for me, but than I tried to improve it:o) It seems I have a problem with defining the new one/last row. 'Dim thelastRow As Long, Dim iCntr As Long, Dim newRow As Long, Dim rnglast As Long....rnglast = Sheets("Log").Cells.Find("*", [b1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row...... thelastRow = Worksheets("Log").Range("B" & rnglast).End(xlUp).Offset(-1).Row, newRow = Worksheets("Log").Range("B" & rnglast).rnglast.End(xlUp).Row' Is this wrong? It is doing nothing and giving no mistake on debug.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:
to find duplicate rows, first sort by col. B,C,D. Duplicates will be in adjacent rows then.
No concatenation of cell values is needed, just an `IF` with multiple conditions.
To restore the original order, insert a helper column with the original row numbers and after processing, sort by it. You may need to adjust the column number (const `seqcolumn`) to be higher than the last column needed for comparisons.
To speed things up, copy the entire data into an array and loop through it (read-only). This is way faster than working on the sheet itself. No need to copy the array back onto the sheet as it's read-only.
While looping through the array, collect all row numbers to be marked in a VBA collection.
After scanning, loop over all collected rows and mark the rows on sheet. Color a column range at once, not single cells.

```
Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn()
' mark rows with duplicates in columns B and C with color; yellow if D is dup, red if not
' 2015-12-27
' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475622/how-to-concatenate-columns-and-find-duplicates-within

    Const seqcolumn = 11  ' helper column to restore original order after sorting
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim table As Range
    Dim row As Long, markedRow As Variant
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim lastB As Variant, lastC As Variant, lastD As Variant
    Dim addedPrev As Boolean
    Dim dupes As New Collection

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' count last used row from column C
    lastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row
    ' insert sequence number column to the far left = A
    Columns(seqcolumn).Insert
    For row = 2 To lastRow
        Cells(row, seqcolumn) = row
    Next row

    ' B&C duplicate lines, if D identical=yellow, else =red
    Rows("2:" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=Cells(2, 2), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Cells(2, 3) _
        , Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Cells(2, 4), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:= _
        xlSortNormal
    Set table = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lastRow, 4)) ' oldB, oldC, oldD
    ' reset previous marks
    table.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    arr = table

    ' find duplicates (B and C equal); if D equal, yellow, else red
    lastB = arr(2, 1)
    lastC = arr(2, 2)
    lastD = arr(2, 3)
    addedPrev = False
    For row = 3 To lastRow
        If arr(row, 1) = lastB And arr(row, 2) = lastC Then
            If arr(row, 3) = lastD Then
                If Not addedPrev Then dupes.Add (row - 1)
                dupes.Add row
            Else
                If Not addedPrev Then dupes.Add -(row - 1)
                dupes.Add -row

                lastD = arr(row, 3)
            End If
            addedPrev = True
        Else
            lastB = arr(row, 1)
            lastC = arr(row, 2)
            lastD = arr(row, 3)
            addedPrev = False
        End If
    Next row

    ' mark rows
    For Each markedRow In dupes
        If markedRow > 0 Then
            Range(Cells(markedRow, 2), Cells(markedRow, 7)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Else
            Range(Cells(-markedRow, 2), Cells(-markedRow, 7)).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next markedRow

    ' sort to original order
    Rows("2:" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=Cells(2, seqcolumn), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    Columns(seqcolumn).Delete
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```